# Magento Generating Random URLS

Tags: url, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404, magento-1.7

I am using Magento 1.7.0.2.

I am having problems with the system generating random urls which are generating 404's when google crawls the website.

They have an unusual format and I have no idea why they are being generated.

```
store_id/2/entity_id/148/entity_type/catalog
```

I have never had this problem before - does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by aheadWorks Sociable Plugin, this was causing us a lot of problems with SEO, glad we have it fixed now.